# Unary operator following arithmetic operator (use parentheses) at (1)

Tags: fortran, warnings

When I am compiling a Fortran Code I am getting the following warning:

nse3dmpi_subs.f:603:15:

```
  .        -HALF*aimag(k3(k)*(uh(i,j,k,1)*conjg(uconv3h(i,j,k,1))-
           1
```

Warning: Extension: Unary operator following arithmetic operator (use parentheses) at (1)

How do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: It's very difficult to be certain from just that line but I'd guess an incorrectly written *continuation line* in *fixed-form source*.  Search around on SO for questions and answers covering those topics.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is very incomplete. You are only showing the error message, but you should also show your code an the command you use to compile it.

Comment: Compiler guesses you mean (÷HALF)

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error recently.  It happened because I ended one line with "+", did a line continuation, and started the next line with "-".  I got rid of it by taking the "-" out of the second line and replacing the "+" with a "-".  Instead of:

```
      x = (really long expression) +
     1      -2.*(other long expression)
```

I needed:

```
      x = (really long expression) -
     1     2.*(other long expression)
```

Alternatively, I could have done:

```
      x = (really long expression) +
     1      (-2.*(other long expression))
```

Comment: @francescalus   Yep.  Sorry.  Edited.